# How do I show multiple custom cells using objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a few custom cells that I would like to display information on. I made 2 new cells however it is only returning one cell. The top most cell's identifier is "Cell" and the bottom one is "quantityCell". I would like the product description to be on the top cell and the quantity on the bottom cell. The output I am getting now is only the quantity cell showing, but not the product cell. If I remove the quantity cell, the product cell will show. How should I go about doing this?
 Thank you

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *quantityCellIdentifier = @"quantityCell";
    UITableViewCell *quantityCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:quantityCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    DisplayInventoryTableViewController *inventoryItem = [[DisplayInventoryTableViewController alloc]init];

    self.productName = [inventoryItem getProductTitle];
    productTitle = self.productName;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = productTitle;
        NSLog(@"productTitle %@", self.productName);
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Product Title";

    self.productQuantity = [inventoryItem getQuantity];
    quantityCell.textLabel.text = @"Quantity";
    quantityCell.detailTextLabel.text = self.productQuantity;

    /*
    // Configure the cell...

   // cell.textLabel.text = productTitle;
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Product Name";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = productTitle;
    */
    return cell;return quantityCell;
}
```

Comment: Thank you all, I ended up using a dictionary that returns all of the keys and values to the cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

The you can't return 2 parameters in the same time on a method. So where you say:

```
return cell;return quantityCell;
```

Only cell is being returned, the method ends on the first return.

### Solution

You need to make logic which one time returns **topCell** and the other time **bottomCell**

So in your case you just need to have indexPath.row **modulus** 2, which can take any value and returns only 0 on even numbers and 1 on odd numbers.

So your code should be like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"";
    
    if (indexPath.row%2==0) {
        //Get the top cell
        CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    } else {
        //Get bottom cell
        CellIdentifier = @"quantityCell";
    }
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    DisplayInventoryTableViewController *inventoryItem = [[DisplayInventoryTableViewController alloc]init];
    if (indexPath.row%2==0) {
        //Customize topCell
        self.productName = [inventoryItem getProductTitle];
        productTitle = self.productName;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = productTitle;
        NSLog(@"productTitle %@", self.productName);
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Product Title";
    } else {
        //Customize bottom cell
        self.productQuantity = [inventoryItem getQuantity];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Quantity";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = self.productQuantity;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return cell;
return quantityCell;
```

The above 2 line you wrote in your function! After return statement the method stop executing further lines.

You could do something like this:

```
self.productName = [inventoryItem getProductTitle];
self.productQuantity = [inventoryItem getQuantity];
productTitle = self.productName;
if(indexPath.row == 0) {
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = productTitle;
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Product Title";
    return cell;
}
else {
    NSString *quantityCellIdentifier = @"quantityCell";
    UITableViewCell *quantityCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:quantityCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    quantityCell.textLabel.text = @"Quantity";
    quantityCell.detailTextLabel.text = self.productQuantity;
    return quantityCell;
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I ended up using a dictionary that returns all of the keys and values to the cells.

```html
    NSDictionary *inventoryDictionary = @{
                                          
                                          @"Quantity"      : productQuantity,
                                          @"Price"         : productPriceValue,
                                          @"Product Title" : productTitle
                                          
                                          };

        NSLog(@"ProductStrings: %@", inventoryDictionary);

    NSString *keys = [inventoryDictionary allKeys][indexPath.row];
    NSString *providerNameString = keys;
    cell.textLabel.text = providerNameString;
    
        NSString *Values = [inventoryDictionary allValues][indexPath.row];
    NSString *providerNameValue = Values;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = providerNameValue;
    
    return cell;
```